# Unity To xcode Error

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

[Here's the Errors][1]
i'm Getting this Message Everytime with every code i export from unity

```
#if UNITY_CAN_USE_METAL

#import <Metal/Metal.h>
#import <QuartzCore/CAMetalLayer.h>

#else

typedef NSUInteger MTLPixelFormat;
enum
{
    MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm,
    MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB,
};
 ......................

#endif
```

Comment: Always paste the text of your errors in here, do not use graphics for text. Make sure your posted example code is complete, i.e., add the missing `#endif`.

Answer (score 0):

I lack the reputation to comment above, so:

In Unity-iPhone/Classes/Unity/UnityMetalSupport.h, lines 20-25:

```
typedef NSUInteger MTLPixelFormat;
enum
{
    MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm,
    MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB,
};
```

Xcode 9.0.1 gives the following errors:

```
Line 20: Typedef redefinition with different types ('NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') vs 'enum MTLPixelFormat')
Line 23: Redefinition of enumerator 'MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm'
Line 24: Redefinition of enumerator 'MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB'
```

My xcodeproj was generated by Unity 5.5.2f1.